# PHP how come global variable does not work when utlizing ajax to fetch content?

Tags: php

So I have this code snippet.

```
function get_box_ajax() {
    global $box;

    $box = get_box(); // creates box object

    ob_start();
    get_template( '/filepath/content.php' );
    $output = ob_get_clean();
}

// in the content.php file

global $box;

<form action="<?php echo box_url( $box->url ); ?>" method="post"> // error on this line
...
</form>
```

So with this code, I am getting a non-object error on the call to $box->url.  Take note this is done via ajax.

So I thought in my ajax function I have already globalized $box and that will take but it doesn't seem to work?  Any thoughts?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense... when is `get_box_ajax()` called?

Comment: Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't global variables with the use of `global` keyword scoped per request?  I can't seem to find the docs for it.  And another point to note is that every ajax request is considered different request.

Comment: Well, `get_box_ajax()` creates the $box object right? so that kind is relevant since that's your error..

Comment: @vinodadhikary +1 That seems like a good idea where the confusion is..

Comment: @vinodadhikary You are correct. PHP doesn't have global variables as such. They're short-lived per request, and do not persist. OP certainly has not explained the relation between the shown output code and the AJAX request.

Comment: @Ben - I don't see how that is relevant at all, I could have a simple link that says "click me" and that fires that ajax call...So how would that link be relevant to my issue?

Comment: @mario - that is just a typo...everything works as should other than that notice error...

Comment: @Rick Ask yourself.. when is `$box` created before calling `$box->url`

Comment: @Ben - its already there in the code...

Comment: @Rick.. not where.. *when*

Comment: @Ben - perhaps I have no idea what you're asking because its all there in the code.  When the ajax function is called, the box object is created then and there and globalized so that when fetching the template file, it will persist.  It is all in one ajax request...

Comment: @Rick Show us the code for `get_box()` then

Comment: Why do you need to use the global variable at all? You could just use `box_url(get_box()->url)` in the html form output snippet.

Comment: @mario - because I don't have control of that form...that is some other plugin...

Comment: @Ben - I did a var_dump on $box after creating it and it comes back with all the methods as should....the issue isn't here as I stated...From my code I just thought by declaring it global, the file I am getting via output buffer should use that global as well...but it doesn't is why I am baffled...

Comment: @Rick, have you read this doc, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php? I think it's a worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

When is your `get_box_ajax` function called? And what does the function `get_box` do? Both things are relevant.

I don't think the problem is whether `box` is global or not (which it is), but rather if the `url` variable of `box` is being defined or if `box` is being initialized at all.

Comment: This is not the issue as everything works in my code..I get what I expect back from the ajax call albeit the error i get as well...I get all the content back because the $box->url has a fallback if nothing is passed...

Comment: @Rick Try doing a `var_dump($box);` after your `global $box;` declaration. The error is not in what you showed us but rather in what you didn't show (e.g. the `get_box` function or the AJAX request).

Comment: Another words, in my AJAX function I can do this echo $box->url and it would give me the URL...

Comment: So I am getting an impression that this has something to do with the output buffering...but am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Set box to null before the function. There's no reference in the global scope

```
$box = null;
function get_box_ajax() {
    global $box;

    $box = get_box();
```

Change the start to that

Comment: sorry I don't follow, can you please elaborate.

Comment: why would that solve the problem "non-object error on the call to $box->url" ?

Comment: Because box isn't in the global scope so its not an object. It you make it null outside of the function. The function then over rides and the full reference is in the global scope

Comment: First, that's not right, you don't need to set global variable to null to use it. Second that doesn't fix the problem with $box not being an object when using `$box->url`, that function isn't called..

Comment: No not to null. But it needs to be set. Null seemed appropriate. and if its not in scope then its not an object. Look at the docs all examples the variable is first declared outside of the function and not inside ...

Comment: @user1281385 you really don't need to declare global variables anywhere, you just need to use `global` in any of the scopes you want to use it..

Comment: Not true. http://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101202144212AAsjj5e try it yourself

Comment: No, that's incorrect. The `global` keyword creates a zval reference in the local scope. A variable previously unset in the global/shared scope will still be accessible, even if unset. It does not need a value assignment beforehand. The act of creating said reference in the function implicitly `NULL`s the global, sans notice. Which is why it is rightly advised to do predefine global vars.